# Getting lazy instance via kernel (Ninject)

Tags: ninject

I am using Ninject in substitution of MEF and I was wondering if it's possible to get lazy instances via standard kernel methods and not via [inject] .
I need this since when building up my application's menu I have to pass all particular view models and then if the user is enabled on that function to add it to the menu

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, you can inject a [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the value will only be instanciated when you access `Lazy<T>.Value`.
You can also inject a `Func<T>` and use it to create `T` whenever you like (with the func, every call creates a new instance).

Of course you can also do `IResolutionRoot.Get<Lazy<T>>()` or `IResolutionRoot.Get<Func<T>>()`, but usually that's a sign of bad design (service locator), so use constructor injection when it's feasible.

EDIT: When is the "enabling of the user" happening? Is it a one time thing? What is being displayed before and after?
There might be other/better designs to achieve this but it's hard to say with that little information.

Comment: Hello,each viewmodel I've has a property defined in the ITaggable interface that tells a role name , when a user is logged it has a list of roles and based on this I add items to the menu. Right now all the viewmodel have been instantiated since it's not lazy... I was looking for a better approach and this seems to be the way

Comment: To access the `ITaggable` interface you will still need to have an instance. So you will still need to instantiate all view models, then check whether the role matches,... so you don't really win anything with lazy. If you don't want to instantiate the view models the role must be available statically. You could also use conditional bindings: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: My app works at this way : I've an xml that has the whole menu structure (and has a property tag which reflects the viewmodel's tag and the user's role) then I've the roles list of the currently logging user and last the IEnumerable<ITaggable> (which represents all the viewmodels). right now if a user is currently enable to a single viewmodel my code iterates trought all the viewmodel and I find it quite useless..

Comment: Exactly. That's why you should look into contextual bindings ;-).
You could do something like: `IResolutionRoot.GetAll<IViewModel>(new EnabledViewModelTagsParameter("tag1", "tag2");` and then @binding set a condition that there must be an `EnabledViewModelTagsParameter` with a matching tag. You can even convention bind this: instead if `ITaggable` use a `[Taggable]` attribute on the view model. Do you need more information?

Comment: What's the advantage of using an attribute instead of the interface? I've another question... currently I've a static reference to the kernel in my NinjectBootstrapper , ninject doesn't provide a kernel instance itself?

Comment: since you can instantiate multiple kernels (`new StandardKernel()`), it does not make sense that ninject provides you with a static reference. Usally you don't need a kernel reference except for `IKernel.Load` and `.Dispose()`. You can inject `IResolutionRoot` (this is resolution interface of the kernel) and use this.

Comment: Advantage of attribute: the tag/role is available statically. You don't need to instantiate the view model to check the tag/role. So you only instantiate view models which the user has roles enabled for.

Comment: Thanks again...but this way if I need to create a menu at runtime I ve to use an instance to "force" the visibility...thanks